# Cannot get generic type T of an object

Tags: c#, generics

I'm passing objects to a generic method, called fromProperty and toProperty. The objects are lists of generic type  but when I try to get the generic type I get an  'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' exception. This something to do with the method itself being generic, but it needs to stay that way.

```
    private static Dictionary<string, List<object>> GetListAttributeDifferences<TFrom, TTo>(TFrom fromProperty, TTo toProperty)
        where TFrom : class
        where TTo : class
    {
        //Get types for list containing types
        Type fromPropertyListContainingType = fromProperty.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0];
        Type toPropertyListContainingType = toProperty.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0]; return null;}
```

This method is called this way

```
        public static Dictionary<string, List<object>> GetAttributeDifferences<TFrom, TTo>(TFrom fromObject, TTo toObject)
                where TFrom : class
                where TTo : class

            if (fromObject is IList && toObject is IList)
            {
                Dictionary<string, List<object>> listAttributeDifferences = GetListAttributeDifferences(fromObject, toObject);
            }}
```

Comment: Please show how you call this method

Comment: Does the type of `fromProperty` have generic type arguments? IOW, is `fromProperty` something like `List<object>` such that it has a generic argument? There's nothing in the signature that indicates it does...

Answer (score 0):

Use `GetGenericArguments`, which is a **method** of `System.Type`:

```
private static Dictionary<string, List<object>> GetListAttributeDifferences<TFrom, TTo>(TFrom fromProperty, TTo toProperty)
        where TFrom : class
        where TTo : class
{
    //Get types for list containing types
    Type fromPropertyListContainingType = fromProperty.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
    Type toPropertyListContainingType = toProperty.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This solution still give me 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' exception.

Comment: So they are not generic. Test it before by using `if (fromPropertyListContainingType.GetType().IsGenericType) {}`

Comment: You're right, this evaluates to false -- how can an object be passed as a generic list and lose this status?

Comment: How are you calling `GetAttributeDifferences`?

Comment: If you know that this is a list why don't you change the function signature to:  private static Dictionary<string, List<object>> GetListAttributeDifferences<TFrom, TTo>(List<TFrom> fromProperty, List<TTo> toProperty) and then just use type TFrom and TTo?